# scala - add a tuple to listBuffer

Tags: scala

I'd like to add a three-integer tuple to a ListBuffer. intuitively, my first try is the code snippet 1, which has a syntax error,according to the compiler. Then, I've tried the snippet 2 and 3, both will work. So could someone explain to me why the code in snippet 1 syntactically wrong.

snippet 1

```
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    val b : ListBuffer[(Int, Int,Int)] = ListBuffer()
    b += (1,1,1)
```

snippet 2

```
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    val b : ListBuffer[(Int, Int,Int)] = ListBuffer()
    b += ((1,1,1))
```

snippet 3

```
    import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
    val b : ListBuffer[(Int, Int,Int)] = ListBuffer()
    val i = (1,1,1)
    b += i
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
b += (1,1,1)
```

is interpreted as

```
 b.+=(1,1,1)
```

which looks like a function call passing three parameters to +

Adding another pair of parens means it's interpreted as

```
b.+=((1,1,1))
```

which is passing the expected tuple.

Declaring the argument separately in

```
val i = (1,1,1)
```

also doesn't have that interpretation problem so is OK too.

Comment: Is this considered a bug in scala?

Comment: _"Is this considered a bug in scala?"_ No. But the error message could have been more informative.